# How to make the directive "initialization" use ; in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

So I have a predicate named ***confirm***.

This predicate has 3 possible shapes:

```
confirm([ ]):-!.
confirm():-
confirm([arc(X,Y)|T]) :-
```

I want this predicate to auto-activate when I execute my file. I have read that in order to achieve this, I need to use the directive ***initialization***.

So, first I execute my file with the interpreter:

```
myName@myName-VirtualBox:~/dir/$ swipl fileONE.pl
```

Then inside my code, I have this:

```
:- initialization(confirm).
```

The thing is it only works partially... Let me explain.

I have some graph structure in ANOTHER file - let's call it fileTWO.pl. The graphs are of the form:

```
:- dynamic arc/2.
:- dynamic graphe/2.

graph(g1,[arc(x,y),arc(x2,y2),arc(x3,y3)...]).
graph(g2,[arc(a,b),arc(a2,b2),arc(a3,b3)...]).
graph(g3,[arc(a,b),arc(a2,b2),arc(a3,b3)...]).
...
```

Basically, the ***confirm*** predicate asserts the arcs into my "database". If I have 3 graphs, like in the example above (g1, g2, g3), then I need to use **;** when using ***confirm*** in order to add all the graphs.

So here is how I would use my predicate ***confirm*** manually:

```
?- confirm().
true ;
true ;
true .
```

And that's exactly what I want.

**So here is my problem.** When I use the directive ***initialization***, it only does the first **true**, if I can say. So only my first graph would be asserted.

Therefore my question is how to get a predicate to execute at the launch of my file and execute every "instance" or every "cycle" (I am not sure how to say).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use instead:

```
:- initialization((confirm,fail;true)).
```

I.e. a *failure-driven loop* as the initialization goal.

Comment: Thank you very much, Paulo. You're a savior. Do you know where I can find a more ''serious'' Prolog documentation than https://www.swi-prolog.org/? I know it sounds dumb since this looks like the main website, but there are really few details on this website.

Comment: I list some Prolog online learning resources at https://logtalk.org/related.html#prolog-on-line-learning-resources The reddit Prolog channel lists a few others https://www.reddit.com/r/prolog/ There's also the comp.lang.Prolog FAQ at https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.prolog